# Many to many polymorphic association in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, database-schema

A `Video`, a `Song` and an `Article` can have many `Tags`. And each `Tag` also can have many `Video, Songs or Articles`. So I have 5 models: `Video, Song, Article, Tag and Taggings`.

Here are these models:

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tags, :through => :taggings
end

class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tags, :through => :taggings
end

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tags, :through => :taggings
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :articles
  has_many :videos
  has_many :songs
  belong_to :taggings, :polymorphic => true #is this correct?
end
```

The database definition of `Taggings`

```
create_table "taggings", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer  "tag_id"
  t.string   "taggable_type"
  t.integer  "taggable_id"
  t.datetime "created_at",    :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at",    :null => false
end
```

`Taggings` model:

```
class Taggings < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tag                           #is this correct?
  belong_to :taggable, :polymorphic => true #is this correct?
end
```

The issue I'm worried by is, do I have right definitions of model (`belongs_to`, `has_many`?) ? My gut tells me that I missed something. I've seen many articles and I'm quite confused by them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need these changes:

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base # or Song, or Article
  has_many :taggings, :as => :taggable  # add this      
  has_many :tags, :through => :taggings # ok


class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  # WRONG! Tag has no tagging_id
  # belong_to :taggings, :polymorphic => true

  has_many :taggings # make it this way

  # WRONG! Articles are available through taggings
  # has_many :articles

  # make it this way
  with_options :through => :taggings, :source => :taggable do |tag|
    tag.has_many :articles, :source_type => 'Article'
    # same for videos
    # and for songs
  end
```

About [`with_options`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-with_options).

Your class `Taggings` seems ok **except its name**. It has to be singular, `Tagging`:

```
class Tagging < ActiveRecord::Base # no 's'!
  belongs_to :tag                           
  belong_to :taggable, :polymorphic => true 
end
```

Comment: Thank you jdoe. That's right about Taggins, it's should be singular. Can you please show me how to it without using `with_options`? I know, it would probably be more complex, but it's okay for me. I just want to figure out what I missed.

Comment: @Grienders `has_many :articles, :through => :taggings, :source => :taggable, :source_type => 'Article'`

Comment: Why do you say `has_many :articles, :through => :taggings, :source => :taggable, :source_type => "Article"` but `has_many :articles, :through => :taggings, :source => :taggable(_type or _id?), :source_type => "Article"` And what does `as` mean in `has_many :taggings, :as => :taggable.` BTW, I red about polymorphic ass-s.

Comment: @Grienders `has_many :articles, :through => :taggings` without `:source => :taggable, :source_type => 'Article'` would try to find `article` association in the Tagging class (which is absent). Specifying `:source => :taggable` says to check `taggable` association. But `Tagging#taggable` is polymorphic, so we need to provide the type of the object we are interested in (with `Article` in its `taggable_type` field in this case).

Comment: @Grienders And about `:as`. `has_many :taggings, :as => :taggable` for  the `Video` class says to check `taggable_id` instead of `video_id`. You just have to remember: `belong_to :taggable, :polymorphic => true` (in Tagging) leads to many lines in other classes with `:as => :taggable` set in its association. If something has ability to contain many types, then many types have to be declared as "ready to be" in this container via `:as`.